HW Accelerated Video Decoding on Quest 3
I've struggled with this for a while.
I'm building a VR Android app (C++/OpenXR) that receives and displays video from a GStreamer RTP stream. I've been able to successfuly decode two simoultaneous JPEG streams (FullHD@60FPS) with hardware acceleration (at least I think?).
I'm using an Meta Quest 3 headset and when I query its HW codec capabilities, it shows bunch of OMX.qcom.video.decoder.*** HW accelerated codecs.
When trying to search for a GStreamer element that would be able to leverage those, I've read that one should be using androidmedia from gst-plugins-bad which is in referenced in android pugins.mk inside GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS. I'm linking the GStreamer as a shared library in my project and this shared library is packaged using ndk via this tool. Everything points to a direction that the finished .so should contain all that is needed to be able to decode using HW accelerated codecs - but when listing all available elements from GstRegistry, no amcviddec-*** elements are present.
Any ideas?
